# Insert BigDecimal from Java to Decimal in h2 database

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, syntax-error, h2

I have create this table here:
[image]

[image]

As you can see from above. It successfully created a table
However, when I tried this command:
[image]

I also tried to do in the h2 database:
[image]

At this point, I don't know where I did wrong. Is this my syntax or the bigdecimal problem.
Please help me.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code and exception stacktraces. Post them as code formatted text.

Comment: Got it! Will do next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the insert specify the columns by name

```
insert into mystock (name, date, open, high, low, close) values (....);
```

BTW Date is not a good column name

Comment: Yes about that date. This is me learning and I will fix it. Again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
insert into mystock(name, date, open, high, low, close) values (...)
```